# Why SQL statement SELECT ROUND(45.926, -1) FROM DUAL print 50

Tags: sql, rounding

How does dual work? I have executed this with many values `Select Round(45.926,-1) from dual` it prints 50 while
`Select Round(45.926,-2) from dual` prints 0.

Comment: What did you expect when you round to 10^1 and 10^2 ? Also, this has nothing to do with `DUAL`, which is just a dummy table to allow you to issue a SELECT (which always needs a table in Oracle).

Comment: What database? `select round(45.926, -1)` on SQLite produces 46.

Comment: Alway hav a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions142.htm#SQLRF00698)

Answer (score 6):

When using `ROUND` function, the second parameter represents the places after decimal to be taken in result. So, following are results:

```
SELECT ROUND(45.926) FROM dual;
```

Result: 46 because no places after decimal to be considered.

```
SELECT ROUND(45.926, 1) FROM dual;
```

Result 45.9, consider 1 place after decimal

```
SELECT ROUND(45.926, -1) FROM dual;
```

Result: 50, considering the value to be 4.5926, rounding it to 5 and then printing the result.

```
SELECT ROUND(45.926, -2) FROM dual;
```

Result: 0, considering the value to be 0.45926, rounding it to 0 and then printing the result in original 10x which is 0x100 = 0.

If you'd taken,

```
SELECT ROUND(55.926, -2) FROM dual;
```

Then result will be 100 because it would be like, rounding 0.55926 to 1 and then 10x which 1x100 = 100.

Answer (score 0):

`Round(n,m)` - rounds the number n to m decimal places.

For m = -1, it rounds the number to tenth place making 45.926 to 50 as it is greater than 45

For m = -2, it rounds the number to 100 place. Since 45.926 is less than 50, it becomes 0. If you try round(51,-2) you should get 100